# m3u8 Video stops with MediaPlayer: Error (1,-1004)

Tags: android, url, android-mediaplayer, m3u8

I'm playing video from url = http://... /playlist.m3u8

```
    MediaPlayer mVideoPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    ...
    mVideoPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), url);
```

all works fine...but after 5 min video stops with error

```
11-24 17:52:22.519: V/MediaPlayer(2777): message received msg=100, ext1=1, ext2=-1004
11-24 17:52:22.519: E/MediaPlayer(2777): error (1, -1004)
11-24 17:52:22.519: V/MediaPlayer(2777): callback application
11-24 17:52:22.519: V/MediaPlayer(2777): back from callback
11-24 17:52:22.519: E/MediaPlayer(2777): Error (1,-1004)
```

I found in internet that this happens because http server close connection

How to solve this issue on my side?

Comment: You have to fix it on server side.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you play HLS resource via low network connection or server is busy and you cannot reach it.
in this case, android tries to fetch next playlist but fails to connect to server, and after several attempts rises this error.

i think you can simply notify users about bad connection and suggest to reconnect to the server :)

Comment: It's not a bad connection, it's because http server close connection(like timeout of conection) , read my question

Answer (score 0):

`error (1, -1004)` is error fetch m3u8 playlist or it's segment during playback.